# infinite loop in a function called within a thread causes the thread to stay alive

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, interrupt, infinite

```
public class Ex4 extends Thread {
  boolean ans;
  boolean change=false;

  public boolean isPrime(long n, double maxTime) throws RuntimeException {
    final Thread a;
    Thread b;
    final RuntimeException e;
    final long num = n ;
    final double mtime = maxTime;
    a = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
                try{
                    ans = Ex4_tester.isPrime(num);
                    change=true;
                }
                catch ( RuntimeException exp){
                    throw exp;
                };
            }
    };
    a.start();
    try {
        sleep((long)mtime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(a.isAlive()){
        a.interrupt();
    }
    if(a.isInterrupted()){
        throw new RuntimeException("time for check exceeded");
    }
    return ans;
  }
}
```

all works fine, except sometimes Ex4_tester.isPrime goes into infinite loop (its ok, it should do that).
the problem that even though the thread gets interrupted the process keeps running and the thread doesnt actually stop

Comment: Could you please format your code to make it more readable?

Answer (score 2):

A thread getting interrupted doesn't stop it. It just causes the thread to get out of certain wait and sleep states. To have the thread exit an infinite loop based on input from another thread, put an explicit check against an Atomic<> in the loop and have the control thread modify the state of the atomic variable to where thread 'a' will exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Only certain methods like `Object.wait()` will throw `InterruptedException`.  If your thread doesn't call any of those methods, it won't get interrupted.

In other words, you can't asynchronously interrupt a Java thread.  Very few threading systems support asynchronous interruption.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is to set your thread to be daemon, that is call `a.setDaemon(true)` before start. That will make your process will be ended if this is only thread that stayed started.

If you want to interrupt your thread read [this documentation for interrupt method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

`interrupt` method causes `InterruptedException` only when the thread is in certain points of execution (such as `sleep`). Your code has invalid cancellation policy. You should consider another way of stopping your thread.

Comment: the stop and destroy methods are not available so how i stop the thread if interrupt doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

An interrupt requires an explicit check at a point where it is safe by design to interrupt a thread.  If you don't perform this check (or call a method which does) the thread will keep running.